# Am I allowed to sign people up on email list when they connect with Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I am currently making a website, where I require the user to sign up using his/her Facebook Account. I would like to send mails out to my users, but in the connection process, they do not allow me to do that. I COULD send them on to a page where they can sign up for newsletter or not, but I would rather just have it in the same process. Is there any way, they can accept  or decline the option of receiving emails from me? If am trying to make it possible in the Facebook Connection process where they connect to my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you asked for the `email` permission in your sign up form?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-email though obviously you must comply with the relevant policies

Comment: Okay, so as far as I can see, if I ask for that permission, I may send them emails, but within the frames of the policies?

Comment: That is correct, alternatively ask them to enter their email address on a separate page on your website and explicitly opt in to your emails. From a user perspective I'd say your best bet is to get them to opt in to the newsletter regardless, so they can unsubscribe to that, but you could in theory still have their email if you needed to send them an email for another matter (to inform them the site will be down or something)